# Clojure: pass value if it passes predicate truth test

Tags: clojure

Is it possible to remove the let statement / avoid the intermediate 'x' in the following code?:

```
(let [x (f a)]
   (when (pred? x) x))
```

I bumped into this problem in the following use case:

```
(let [coll (get-collection-somewhere)]
   (when (every? some? coll)  ; if the collection doesn't contain nil values
      (remove true? coll)))   ; remove all true values
```

So if the collection is free of nil values, only not-true values remain, like numbers, strings, or whatever.

So, I'm looking for something like this:

```
(defn pass-if-true [x pred?]
   (when (pred? x) x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't want to define that `pass-if-true` function, the best you can do is an anonymous function:

```
(#(when (every? some? %)
    (remove true? %))
 (get-collection-somewhere))
```

You could also extract the predicate and transformation into parameters:

```
(#(when (%1 %3) (%2 %3))
 (partial every? some?)
 (partial remove true?)
 (get-collection-somewhere))
```

Comment: (-> (get-coll) (#(when (every? some? %) (remove true? %))) maybe. well, I'm asking myself why here I'd need the extra-brackets for the anonymous fn. Because: (= (-> 3 inc) (-> 3 (inc))

Comment: (-> 9 #(inc %))  ; Compiler exception

Comment: @AntonHarald Sorry, I was incorrect before. Because `#()` is a reader macro, `#(inc %)` is equivalent to `(fn* [x] (inc x))`, so `(-> 9 #(inc %))` is equivalent to `(-> 9 (fn* [x] (inc x)))`, which then leads to `(fn* 9 [x] (inc x))`.

Answer (score 1):

The `let` form is necessary to prevent your collection-building function from running twice:

`(f a)` or `(get-collection-somewhere)`

This is a typical idiom and you are doing it correctly.

Of course, you don't need the `let` if you already have the collection and are not building inside this expression.

However, you may wish to see `when-let`:

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/when-let

It can save some keystrokes in some circumstances, but this isn't one of them.